# How to modify a table in word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2003

I have tables that I am creating, and I want to be able to modify them through the code in the VBA.

What I need to do to the tables is merge and resize some cells and also add text to some of the cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append on what Lance was saying, here's an example of Merging Cells and setting text in the value of those merged cells:

```
Dim myCells As Range
With ActiveDocument
    Set myCells = .Range(Start:=.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, End:=.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.End)
    myCells.Select
End With

Selection.Cells.Merge


ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=1).Range.Text = "Value for Merged Cells"
```

NOTE:  The table in this example had three columns and two rows

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the Table object, like

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=2).Range.Text
```

or

```
<some Word.Document here>.
  Content.Tables(1).Columns.SetWidth <columnwidthhere>, wdAdjustSameWidth
```